# methods and logic error

Tags: java, logic

I have a logic error in my `getMinValue()` method. The `getMaxValue()` method works, so I don't understand why the minimum method doesn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FILE {

public static void main(String[] main) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int[] quizArray = new int[20];
    double average = 0.0;
    FileReader myReader = new FileReader(
            "C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\QuizScores.txt");
    BufferedReader intHunter = new BufferedReader(myReader);

    // check through the first line
    String line = intHunter.readLine();

    // If more line go ahead!
    while (line != null) {
        // System.out.println("Inside while loop1");
        StringTokenizer myTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

        while (myTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            // System.out.println("Inside while loop2");
            String text = myTokenizer.nextToken();
            try {
                quizArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(text);
                // print valid number
                System.out.println(quizArray[i]);
                // min & max
                sum += quizArray[i];
                i++;
                counter++;
                // System.out.println(quizArray[i]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                continue;
            }
            // extract integers from a text file, then do the calculation.
        }
        average = (double) sum / counter;
        line = intHunter.readLine();
    }

    intHunter.close();

    System.out.println("The new file is: " + counter + " integers as:"
            + " sum = " + sum + " average " + average + "\n"
            + " The max value is " + getMaxValue(quizArray) + "\n"
            + " The min is " + getMinValue(quizArray));
}

// getting the maximum value
public static int getMaxValue(int[] array) {
    int maxValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = array[i];

        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

// getting the miniumum value
public static int getMinValue(int[] array) {
    int minValue = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minValue) {
            minValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return minValue;

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Always check the length of an array before taking the zeroth element. This will not fix the problem but is good practice.

Comment: Ah Bathsheba said, you should always check for the size of your array.
Did you use a debugger to find out more info? Your function seems good but maybe your input is wrong and so while your code is returning a good answer you are waiting for something else.

Comment: allright, thank you, I will try, but I was trying just to print the minimum value of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating array of 20 so if you are assigning values less than 20 than the other array take it as 0.

Like:
if you provide array as

```
5
6
3
2
1
```

so rest of the 15 elements of array is 0 thats why it gives you answer 0 but in max number the 0 is min so it works good. For your program use dynamic array

Comment: oh, I see I made a mistake in the min max values not thinking of it like you presented, thank you very much!!!